# How should I populate the ViewModel in WPF?

Tags: wpf, viewmodel

I'm new to WPF and I'm writing a simple test app to familiarize myself with it. My test app will detect all joysticks I have attached to my computer and display information about it. So far, I have this ViewModel:

```
public class JoystickViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Joystick> Joysticks { get; set; }

    public JoystickViewModel()
    {
        GetAttachedJoysticks();
    }

    private void GetAttachedJoysticks()
    {
        // populate Joysticks collection by using SlimDX
    }
}
```

And this is my codebehind for my `MainWindow.xaml`:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = new JoystickViewModel();
    }
}
```

And my XAML for `MainWindow`:

```
<Window ...>
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Joysticks}"
                  DisplayMemberPath="Information.ProductName"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I followed a tutorial that also populated the ViewModel in its constructor.

**My question is**, how should I populate the ViewModel? It seems sort of weird to me that I'm population the collection in the ViewModel constructor. Should this logic be in MainWindow's codebehind instead? Or somewhere else altogether? The end goal is to not only have this collection populated, but also updated periodically to reflect the current state (user plugged in new joystick, unplugged existing one, etc...).

Answer (score 2):

The MainWindow code behind is definitively not the place where "business" logic should occur, as the View should be kept as simple as possible.

Keep your fetch/update logic inside of your viewmodel, this way you can test it easily and independently.

From a learning perspective, it's important to keep concerns separated :

- the View is bound to the ViewModel, and has no intelligence
- the ViewModel has knowledge on how to get the Model
- the Model represents the data

In your case, the VM knowledge is at the moment a call inside it's constructor. Later you can change this to call some IJoystickDataService interface, and wire everything using a MVVM framework.

Answer (score 0):

I would have your JoySticks observable collection property (and the code that populates it) in a Model class. The viewmodel simply exposes this same property to the view for binding. The vm should be as thin as possible - ideally just exposing properties that are in the model for binding and not doing any kind of 'business' logic (i.e. populating joystick info as in your case).